# How do I evaluate $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -\infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2-8x+1}-x\right)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

As asked in the title.
I want to know how can I show that the value approaches to positive infinity as x approaches to negative infinity,without looking at its graph.
Besides, I know that I can use the formula $\displaystyle (a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$, but then I don't know what should I do next.

Comment: Try taking the $x^2$ away from the root.Then if you know how limits of polynomials work at infinity you will find it

Comment: Have you tried to find suitable $a$ and $b$ and see what to do next?

Comment: The limit does not exist. Did you mean $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -\infty}(\sqrt{x^2-8x+1}+x)$ ?

Comment: Use $a-b=\frac{a^2-b^2}{a+b}$. You need to modify you question a little bit as told by @Dan.

Comment: If you meant +infiinty, its -4. otherwise the limit does not exist

Comment: Thanks @Dan, I have edited.

Comment: @KelvinMan Look again please.

Comment: @Dan I am asking -x, not +x.

Comment: @Max0815 I know know how to compute +infiinty for this question, but not -infinity.

Comment: The limit does not exist.
This can be rigorously shown by conjugate multiplication
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MNvs.png

Comment: @Max0815 But how do I show that the value approaches to +infinity?

Comment: Multiply by the conjugate (ie sqrt(blah)+x) and then simplify and take limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}(\sqrt{x^2-8x+1}-x)$

$=\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}(\sqrt{x^2-8x+1}-x)\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-8x+1}+x}{\sqrt{x^2-8x+1}+x}\right)$

$=\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\dfrac{-8x+1}{\sqrt{x^2-8x+1}+x}$

Divide top and bottom by $x$. When dividing the bottom by $x$, use $x=-\sqrt{x^2}$. (There is a negative sign, because $x\to -\infty$ so $x<0$.)

$=\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\dfrac{-8+\dfrac{1}{x}}{-\sqrt{1-\dfrac{8}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2}}+1}$

$=\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\dfrac{-8+\dfrac{1}{x}}{-\sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{x}\left(8-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)}+1}$

For large negative $x$, the part inside the square root is a little more than $1$. So the denominator is small and negative. Since the numerator is close to $-8$, the whole thing is large positive.

So the limit is $+\infty$, or you could say the limit does not exist.

Comment: Sorry @Dan but I just edited my describtion. Please look at my describtion again.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to change variables: $x \mapsto -x$. Your problem then becomes
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \big( \sqrt{x^2 + 8x +1} + x\big).$$
If we consider only $x > 0$ (which is fine as you are taking the limit as $x \rightarrow \infty$) you get
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\big(\sqrt{x^2 + 8x +1} + x\big) > \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{x^2} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}x.$$
The inequality is justified as the left hand side is an increasing function. By comparison, since the right hand side tends to infinity, so must the left hand side.

Comment: Nice approach, but personally I would not use limit notation in the inequality.

Comment: @Dan That's a good point, I suppose I should have kept them separate.

Comment: Yes I agree with Dan, since the expression diverges, we can use the following notation $$\sqrt{x^2 + 8x +1} + x >\sqrt{x^2} =x\to \infty$$